# Label Encoder multiple levels

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using python label encoder to transform my data. Here is my sample data.

```
                         Database      Target    Market_Description    Brand  \
0            CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others    NaN  Shanghai Hyper total  O.Brand   
1            CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others    NaN  Shanghai Hyper total  O.Brand   
2            CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others    NaN  Shanghai Hyper total  O.Brand   

  Sub_Brand Category                   Class_Category  
0       NaN      NaN  Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1  
1       NaN      NaN  Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1  
2       NaN      NaN  Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1
```

I am applying the transformation across all columns

```
df3 = CountryDF.apply(preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

When I check the unique values for Target column, it says,

```
>>> print pd.unique(CountryDF.Target.ravel())

>>> [nan 'Elder' 'Others' 'Lady']
```

But when i check the same after transformation, I am getting multiple levels.

```
>>> print pd.unique(df3.Target.ravel())
>>> [ 40749 667723 667725 ...,  43347  43346  43345]
```

I am not sure how this works? I expected four unique values as I thought the transform implementation works by getting unique values and assigning sorted numpy on each, can anyone help me understand this.

EDIT :- This dataset is a subset of a big dataset. Does that have any relation to this?

EDIT2 :- @Kevin I tried what you suggested, its weird. see this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the large dataset is affecting your outcome.  The purpose of [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) is to transform the prediction targets (In your case, I'm assuming, the `Target` column).  From the [`User Guide`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#preprocessing-targets):

> LabelEncoder is a utility class to help normalize labels such that they contain only values between 0 and n_classes-1.

Here's an example, notice I changed the values of `Target` in your example `CountryDF`, just for demonstration purposes:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

CountryDF = pd.DataFrame([['CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others',np.nan,'Shanghai Hyper total','O.Brand',np.nan,np.nan,'Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1'],
                              ['CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others','Elder','Shanghai Hyper total','O.Brand',np.nan,np.nan,'Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1'],
                              ['CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others','Others','Shanghai Hyper total','O.Brand',np.nan,np.nan,'Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1'],
                              ['CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others','Lady','Shanghai Hyper total','O.Brand',np.nan,np.nan,'Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1'],
                             ['CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others',np.nan,'Shanghai Hyper total','O.Brand','S_B1',np.nan,'Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1'],
                             ['CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others',np.nan,'Shanghai Hyper total','O.Brand','S_B2',np.nan,'Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1']],
                            columns=['Database','Target','Market_Description','Brand','Sub_Brand', 'Category','Class_Category'])
```

First, initialize the `LabelEncoder`, then fit and transform the data (while assigning the transformed data to a new column).

```
le = LabelEncoder() # initialze the LabelEncoder once

#Create a new column with transformed values.
CountryDF['EncodedTarget'] = le.fit_transform(CountryDF['Target'])
```

Notice, the last column, `EncodedTarget` is a transformed copy of `Target`.

```
CountryDF

Database    Target  Market_Description  Brand   Sub_Brand   Category    Class_Category  EncodedTarget
0   CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others  NaN     Shanghai Hyper total    O.Brand     NaN     NaN     Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1   0
1   CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others  Elder   Shanghai Hyper total    O.Brand     NaN     NaN     Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1   1
2   CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others  Others  Shanghai Hyper total    O.Brand     NaN     NaN     Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1   3
3   CN_Milk powder_Incl_Others  Lady    Shanghai Hyper total    O.Brand     NaN     NaN     Hi Cal Adult Milk Powders- C1   2
```

I hope this helps clear up `LabelEncoder`.  If this doesn't fully answer your question, it might lead you down the right path toward transforming your features (which may be what you're trying to do?) -- Check out [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)

**EDIT**
I added two additional rows to `CountryDF` (see above), it has  two unique values to the `Sub_Brand` column, which follow a series of consecutive `NaN`.  I'm stumped as to why you're seeing this behavior, it works for me, pandas 0.17.0 and scikit 0.17.

```
df3 = CountryDF.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
df3
Database    Target  Market_Description  Brand   Sub_Brand   Category    Class_Category
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   3   0   0   0   2   0
3   0   2   0   0   0   3   0
4   0   0   0   0   1   4   0
5   0   0   0   0   2   5   0
```

I can't reproduce your problem, Do you have a link to your data?

```
pd.unique(CountryDF.Target.ravel())    
array([nan, 'Elder', 'Others', 'Lady'], dtype=object)
pd.unique(df3.Target.ravel())
array([0, 1, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Alright, so I understand your point. LabelEncoder is only to transform the prediction targets. Cant we use the same for transforming the features? Am not sure why my transformation creating this [ 40749 667723 667725 ...,  43347  43346  43345]

Comment: And I am not trying to predict the Target column, I am trying to predict "Class_Category" column. I am not using the OneHotEncoder mainly because my features has more than 190 unique values in each, by doing OneHotEncoder, this will increase the the number of columns a lot.

Comment: See the edit, I'm curious if the last two lines come out as I expected, it's tough without the dataset.

Comment: I just updated the question @kevin. Its giving me different number.